# Django - NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'bha' with no arguments not found

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-urls

**project/urls.py** - Here, I passed in regex for primary key

```
from django.urls import path, re_path, include
from contextual import views

urlpatterns = [
    url('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('well_list/', include([

        re_path(r'^$', views.WellList_ListView.as_view(), name='well_list'),
        re_path(r'^create/', views.AddWell_CreateView.as_view(), name='create'),
        re_path(r'^(?P<pk>[-\w]+)/contextual/', include('contextual.urls')),

        ]))
]
```

**contextual/urls.py**

```
app_name = 'contextual'

urlpatterns = [

    re_path(r'^$', base_views.ContextualMainView.as_view(), name='main'),
    re_path(r'^bha/$', base_views.BHA_UpdateView.as_view(), name='bha'),

]
```

**views.py**

```
class ContextualMainView(DetailView):
    template_name = 'contextual_main.html'
    model = models.WellInfo


class WellList_ListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'well_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'well_info'
    model = models.WellInfo

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        # get string representation of field names in list
        context['fields'] = [field.name for field in models.WellInfo._meta.get_fields()]

        # nested list that has all objects' all attribute values
        context['well_info_values'] = [[getattr(instance, field) for field in context['fields']] for instance in context['well_info']]

        # includes well instance objects & values string list for each well
        context['well_info_zipped'] = zip([instance for instance in context['well_info']], context['well_info_values'])

        return context

class BHA_UpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'contextual_BHA.html'
    model = models.WellInfo
    fields = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('well_list')
```

**well_list.html** - primary key is provided in html

```
<tbody>
  {% for well_instance, values in well_info_zipped %}
  <tr>
    {% for value in values %}
    <td><a href="{% url 'contextual:main' pk=well_instance.api %}">{{ value }}</a></td>
    {% endfor %}
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

**contextual_main.html** - primary key is NOT provided in html

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover">
  <a href="{% url 'contextual:bha' %}">BHA</a>
</button>
```

And here is the issue: 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/well_list/123412-11-33/contextual/` does not work and gives me error:

```
NoReverseMatch at /well_list/123412-11-33/contextual/
Reverse for 'bha' with no arguments not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['well_list\\/(?P<pk>[-\\w]+)/contextual/bha/$']
```

However, if I modify my **contextual_main.html**, and manually pass in a primary key, it works:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover">
  <a href="{% url 'contextual:bha' pk='123412-11-33' %}">BHA</a>
</button>
```

It seems that I have to pass in primary key again, if I want to access `http://127.0.0.1:8000/well_list/123412-11-33/contextual/bha/`

Why does Django make me to pass in pk again, when I already have passed in pk in the parent url? Since I've already passed in pk in **well_list.html**, which is a parent page of **contextual_main.html**, my understanding is that I don't have to pass it again.

Is there any way to work this around, like making django to just inherit the primary key from parent, or doing it without re-injecting primary key?

Answer (score 0):

`url` template tag does not consider current path in the context. It uses django's `reverse` method to create url from the given parameters.
Quoting the first line from the documentation of url templatetag.

> Returns an absolute path reference (a URL without the domain name) matching a given view and optional parameters.

So in your case, you have to pass `pk` in the `contextual_main.html` to get the url in the html resolved.

Check docs for more details.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Check docs of `reverse` for more details on it.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse